# redirect without using a protocol in APACHE

Tags: apache, webserver

I want to write a httpd configuration redirect, from some page to another, but without forcing an encryption protocol(http/https), I've tried multiple examples, though none of them works. Some of my ideas:

1) RewriteEngine  on

```
RewriteCond "%{HTTP_REFFERER}"  "^/something/$"
RewriteRule "^/something/$" "%{REQUEST_SCHEME}example.com/test/test1.html"
```

2) what I wish would work somehow

```
RewriteRule "^/something/$"   
"%{REQUEST_SCHEME}example.com/test/test1.html.html" [R=301]
```

3) what is working, but as you see I have to use http or https, which I do not want 
`RedirectMatch 301 "^/something/$" "http://example.com/test/test1.html.html"`

Comment: When you say "none of them works" does it mean that no redirect is issued at all, or that scheme is not the one you need?

Comment: @DusanBajic 
No, when I use the last rule, it works, but I have to use directly the protocol (https), which I do not want eventually, I wished it could work with a variable like %{REQUEST_SCHEME} so dpeending on the request that is issued it uses same protocol.

Just how it works with NGINX:
`
server {
 listen 80;
 server_name domain1.com;
 return 301 $scheme://domain2.com$request_uri;
}`

Comment: You should be able to use `%{REQUEST_SCHEME}` in rewrite rules, just keep in mind that it does not include `://` so you need something like `RewriteRule "^/something/$"   
"%{REQUEST_SCHEME}://example.com/test/test1.html" [R=301]`